# Check if config_translation exists in specified language

Tags: 8, entities

The following code loads all configuration entities of a given type:

`$entities = Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')
  ->getStorage('ENTITY_TYPE')
  ->loadMultiple();`

However, this will erroneously include entities that are not translated into the active language via `config_translation`. Worse, regardless of whether a translation has been loaded, `$entity->language()` still returns the original language of the entity.

Is there any way to determine if a given config entity has been translated into the active language, so the untranslated entities can be filtered out?

Comment: Currently our best effort is to check that either `$conf->language()` matches the current language, or `$conf->getOriginal('...', FALSE) !== $conf->get('...')`. This works for most cases, but will obviously fail when the label translates to the same value.